# Cannot properly deploy smart contract with web3 1.2.4 provider in Geth 1.9.8

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I have setup a private Ethereum node using the following configuration for the genesis block:

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 143,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "alloc": {},
    "difficulty" : "0x40000",
    "gasLimit"   : "0x8880000"
}
```

I am running the geth client with the following commands cmd args:

```
geth --port 3000 --networkid 44444 --nodiscover --datadir=./blkchain --maxpeers=0  --rpc --rpcport 8543 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Once it is running I attach the geth JS client using: `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8543`

I have created an account and have unlocked it as well.

I am trying to deploy a very simple smart contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0;

contract UnrealContract {
    function test() public pure returns (uint16) {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

I have tried **both** from Remix IDE and using the web3js library and although the deployment seems to work fine (I'm getting back a contract address) when I call the `test()` method I get a response of 0x0 in Remix while in my Javascript code I get an error:

> Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (5000000) or always failing transaction

No matter the amount of gas and gasprice I set it always seems to return this error. Is this a problem with any of the versions of the software I'm using?

Comment: In Remix try changing the default EVM version in Solidity compiler settings. If that works you need to enable the more recent forks in your genesis file.

Comment: Do your accounts that you are sending transactions from have enough eth / can you check their balance? You may want to pre-fund them in your genesis file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ismael said, the problem seems to have been the fact that I was missing 3 forks:

- petersburg
- constantinople
- byzantium

After adding these at block 0 it started working.